# NPM install not nesting dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having a little bit of trouble with npm. I'm creating a new folder for my app, then `npm init`. I want to add gulp to my dependencies, so i run `npm install --save-dev gulp`. Now when it creates the node_module folder, i was expecting it to contain a gulp folder. But what it does is install all packages like this:

[image: screenshot of the node_modules folder hierarchy]

As i'm starting to learn npm, i'm wondering if this a normal behavior? If yes, is there a way to organize this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you aware of `--save`, `--save-dev` and `-g`? Do you want to install gulp globally?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I wouldn't really install much anything globally these days. Makes version management more of a hassle.

Comment: @AKX hence my question ;)

Comment: Actually i've read about these. I understood that `--save-dev` install the package under `devDependencies`, so that's what i want. But i don't understand why `npm install` installs all these dependencies as i'm only specifying gulp in my package.json devDependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, a flattened `node_modules` tree is the normal and regular behavior these days (for several years now). If you really really *really* don't want that, you could try [`npm install --legacy-bundling`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), but... please don't. :)

You don't need to look into `node_modules` or worry about its organization (unless something breaks), that's done for you by `npm` or `yarn` (or whichever package manager you're using).

You may still find nested modules here and there in the case they're not mutually compatible -- e.g. if `package1` depends on `tool` version 1 and `package2` depends on `tool` version 2, you may end up with

```
node_modules/
  package1/
  package2/
    node_modules/
      tool/       <- version 2
  tool/           <- version 1
```

but still, everything (usually) just works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It just feels weird that it adds all those packages when you only specify one devDependencies.

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript development in the 2010s... :) See https://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/gulp for a visualization of your case.

Comment: Wow that's cool! So if i understand this tool, gulp depends on all these packages that are installed in my node_modules folder, that's why they're here?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the case.